# Installing Open edX Platform: Production and Developer Instances

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, edx

Recently I came across Open Edx as a potential way to implement online learning.  However as I came to know Edx and needed to install it, I faced a few questions. I am currently trying to Install Open Edx developer and production platform instances on the same system without Virtual box. Is this possible?

I read at this page: [Ubuntu Install instructions for Open Edx](https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Ubuntu-12.04-Installation) that you can do a manual installation. Has anybody tried the manual installation and seen the outcome? Is the manual installation without virtual box? This also goes back to the question too, can I also install Open Edx developer and production platforms that run simultaneously on the same Linux installation.

RE: The system I am trying is Ubuntu Alternate 12.04

Answer (score 4):

I've just successfully deployed an edX production fullstack instance in a VPS with Ubuntu 12.04 x64 LTS. I came up with some issues but luckily I can finish the installation. Problem such as:

- could not find pyparsing module to install
- existing mongodb after re-running the ansible command.

I took some notes about this at: http://iambusychangingtheworld.blogspot.com/2014/02/edx-deploying-edx-platform-fullstack-in.html

Feel free to comment!

Comment: Ok I will take this into consideration. Thanks. I guess we can keep in touch.

Comment: Also in the production environment, how do you start the LMS and CMS?

Comment: Hi Eddie. After you installed everything successfully, all services will be started automatically. The LMS, CMS and other services are controlled by supervisord.

Comment: You can find useful edX commands at: https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Managing-the-Production-Stack

Comment: I tried the installation. The devstack works but for some strange reason the production stack doesn't; I cannot access the CMS and LMS. The default services are running but I get the error saying that no edxapp exists. I would have to post that specifically but I have that as a main problem. I have tried the default IP and added that of my own virtual host. Neither the LMS or CMS respond.

Comment: Run this command to see which services are running, then give me the result: sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl -c /edx/etc/supervisord.conf status

Comment: Thank for your response. I am going to try this.

Comment: Your Blog about ports that Open-edX listens on was very informing